# react-phone-number-input code sample using http API

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Just asking how to get this and put it to my API. Here's a link: https://web.5writer.com/user/signup

```json
{
  "countryCallingCode": "374",
  "nationalNumber": "23131223",
  "number": "+37423131223",
  "country": "AM"
}
```

This is the body of my API

```
{ 
     dial_code,
     mobile,
     iso_code
}
```

This is my code

```js
export default function Home() {

    const toast = useToast()
    const router = useRouter();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);
    const [dial_code, setDial] = useState('');
    const [mobile, setMobile] = useState('');
    const [iso_code, setIso] = useState('');

    async function handleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(`https://web.5writer.com/user/signup`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
           dial_code,
           mobile,
           iso_code,
         }),
    })
      .then((res) =>
        res.json().then((body) => ({
          status: res.status,
          body,
        }))
      )
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
        setLoading(false);
        if (resp.body.status === true) {
          setDial('');
          setMobile('');
          setIso('');

          toast({
            title: 'Success!',
            description: resp.body.message,
            status: 'success',
            duration: 6000,
            isClosable: true,
            position: 'top',
            variant: 'left-accent',
          });

          router.push('../AllOrders/dashboard');

        }
    else {
          toast({
            title: 'ERROR!',
            description: resp.body.message,
            status: 'error',
            duration: 6000,
            isClosable: true,
            position: 'top',
            variant: 'left-accent',
          });
        }
      })
      
  }
  

    return (
    
    <div>
      {success && <Notification />}
      <main>
        <Container >
          <Box
            w='17.8em'
            p={0}
            borderRadius='5px'
            mt={3}
            mb={-4}
            mx='auto'
            pos='relative'
            marginLeft='-1em'
          >
            {loading && (
              <Progress
                pos='absolute'
                top='0'
                left='0'
                width='100%'
                isIndeterminate
                borderTopLeftRadius='6px'
                borderTopRighRtadius='6px'
                size='sm'
                colorScheme='blue'
              />
            )}
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <FormControl className="">
                
                <PhoneNumber
                  placeholder="enter phone number"
                  value={dial_code}
                  onChange={(e) => setDial(e.target.value)}
                /> 
    
              </FormControl>
              <div className="form-group2 d-md-flex">
                    <div className="w-50 text-left">
                          <input type="checkbox" className="checkL"/>
                        <div className="remember">
                    I  have read the <a className="terms">Terms and Condition</a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              <Button
                type='submit'
                mt='0'
                size='sm'
                colorScheme='#2CBEFF'
                disabled={loading}
                pos='relative'
                className="lbutton"
              >
                Register
                {/* {loading && <Spinner pos='absolute' color='red.500' />} */}
              </Button>
              <div className="form-group3">
                        <p className="text-center">Already have an account?
                <Link href="/Login"><a data-toggle="tab" className="Log">Log In</a></Link></p>
                  </div>
            </form>
          </Box>
        </Container>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This code is working but the problem is I only got one data using onChange. Is it possible to use 3 onChange? or is there any method to get 3 data in just one input.

Give me a piece of advice thank you.

Comment: Three `onChange` for what? There's only the one input, T&C checkbox, and a submit button.

Comment: yes, the only input you talking about is where I can get the data. So if I add 2 inputs my problem was solved yes it is but I want to get 3 data in just one input.

 These 3 data's I want to get

{ "countryCallingCode": "374",  "number": "+37423131223", "country": "AM" }

and put it to my API body

{ dial_code, mobile, iso_code }

Comment: I guess I'm not following what you mean by "get 3 data in one input"... like you want a person to enter all that into a single input and then parse it out into separate object properties? Or when you say "data" are you referring to state variables? Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are trying to do?

Comment: so it's not possible okay, so what is the alternate solution to that problem?

Comment: sorry about that yes it is a state variable.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, you want one single state, not three, for three separate inputs, and a single change handler? Yes, this is entirely possible. Can you share what you've tried, even if it's not working?

Comment: yes, you absolutely correct. I don't know what to do about the issue so I'm not trying anything because I'm not familiar with it. 

https://catamphetamine.gitlab.io/react-phone-number-input/ 

this is what I'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not entirely clear what your issue is, but based on the comments it seems you want a single state variable and change handler to manage 3 inputs. You generally accomplish this by associating a `name` attribute with each input. The `name` attribute is accessed via the `onChange` event and can update the specific nested state.

Example:

```js
const initialState = {
  country: "",
  countryCallingCode: "",
  number: ""
};

function App() {
  const [{ country, countryCallingCode, number }, setState] = React.useState(
    initialState
  );

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target; // <-- destructure from event
    setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      [name]: value                   // <-- use name as dynamic key
    }));
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      dial_code: countryCallingCode,
      number,
      country
    };
    setState(initialState);
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div>
          <label>
            Country Code
            <input
              type="text"
              value={countryCallingCode}
              name="countryCallingCode"
              onChange={changeHandler}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            Number
            <input
              type="text"
              value={number}
              name="number"
              onChange={changeHandler}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            Country
            <input
              type="text"
              value={country}
              name="country"
              onChange={changeHandler}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

### Update

If you want to use the `PhoneInput` component you need to map ***its*** `onChange` handler to your own since it passes directly the input value to the handler.

```
const changeHandler = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setState((state) => ({
    ...state,
    [name]: value
  }));
};
```

Here the `changeHandler` is expecting an `onChange` event object. You can pass ***any*** object you like, and so long as it has the correct shape and properties the handler can handle it.

```
<PhoneInput
  value={number}
  name="number"
  onChange={(value) =>
    changeHandler({
      target: {
        name: "number",
        value
      }
    })
  }
/>
```

[image: Edit react-phone-number-input-code-sample-using-http-api]

### Update 2

Ok, I think I understand what you're after now. You want just a single phone number input and then to parse the country code, country, and phone number from the single state.

Check [parsePhoneNumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input#parsephonenumberinput-string-phonenumber)

There's no need for any custom `onChange` handlers, just update state with the `PhoneInput` value and when you are ready, parse the state.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(null);

const submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const {
    countryCallingCode: dial_code,
    country: iso_code,
    number: mobile
  } = parsePhoneNumber(state);
  const data = {
    dial_code,
    mobile,
    iso_code
  };
  setState(null);

  // do with data now what you need
};

...

<PhoneInput value={state} onChange={setState} />
```

[image: Edit react-phone-number-input-code-sample-using-http-api (forked)]

Comment: thanks but I already did the same.

my problem was how can you do that method using this input?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input

Comment: @RondelJohnDomingoDecano It's fairly trivial to map the `PhoneInput` change handler to a common change handler. I updated my answer and included a running demo.

Comment: sir, I'm sorry if we don't connect for what I wanted to do or what the issue is. 

yes, you use the <PhoneInput/> and it getting the number, how about country_code and country, they separated to the number.

I want is to put them 3 in the same <PhoneInput/> if possible? thank you.

Comment: @RondelJohnDomingoDecano I see now, so do you mean something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-phone-number-input-code-sample-using-http-api-forked-vdsjx?file=/src/App.js)?

Comment: yes sir that's awesome thank you but I have a problem I don't know why when rename... example when I rename the country to anything else and the value is undefined. Can you explain why?

Comment: @RondelJohnDomingoDecano Sorry, going to need more context there. What are you renaming? What value is undefined?

Comment: for example, if I replace "country" with "iso_code" it does not work the same. when I look in the console yes it changes the "country" to "iso_code" but the value was undefined.

Comment: @RondelJohnDomingoDecano I see, look at how I renamed `countryCallingCode` to `dial_code` when destructuring with `countryCallingCode: dial_code`. If you want to rename `country` to `iso_code` then the syntax is `country: iso_code`.

Comment: Thank you it works, I'm sorry for any dumb questions.

Comment: you are great and awesome please help me with this one 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68662526/multipart-form-data-not-working-but-when-i-use-application-json-it-works?noredirect=1#comment121345120_68662526

Answer (score 0):

hi that's a little dirty but you can create your state somethings like this

```
let [values,setValues] = useState({phoneNumber : '', dial:'', code:''});
let [inputState, setInputState] = useState('phoneNumber');
const onInputChange = (e) => {
  const { target : { value } } = e;
  setValues(preventValues => ({...preventValues, inputState : value}))
} 

const handleSubmit = (inputStateName) => {
// do your functionality then
setInputState(inputStateName);
}
```

Comment: what functionality do I need to put in handleSubmit?

Comment: in there you have access to your datas , you can do what you want and then , change the input name